# why is Image size reset for me when i add a < a > tag

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

I have a simple image that has a size attribute added using CSS.
I decided to make the image clickable by adding a `<a>` tag hoping nothing will change. But the whole image has been reset and i cant change the size without removing the `<a>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><header><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></header></a>
```

**CSS**

```
header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Additionally, another React project is having the same issue:

```js
// the css for "catImg"
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    catImg: {
        "&:hover": {
            boxShadow: "10px 5px 5px black;",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
        }
    }
}))
.
.
.
<ImageListItem className={classes.catImg}>
                  {/* <a> */}
                   <img
                   src={url}
                   key={cat.token_id} />
                  {/* </a> */}
</ImageListItem>
```

EDIT:

Putting the `a` tag outside the `ImageListItem` makes it work correctly.

```js
// the css for "catImg"
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    catImg: {
        "&:hover": {
            boxShadow: "10px 5px 5px black;",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
        }
    }
}))
.
.
.
<a href="something">
<ImageListItem className={classes.catImg}>
                   <img
                   src={url}
                   key={cat.token_id} />
</ImageListItem>
<a/>
```

Comment: Works fine for me and the a-tag is not interfering in any way. Are you sure this is the *only* code you have? Check if you have set any styles for the a-tag.

Comment: More information is needed to answer this. Could you provide a working [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) demonstrating what it looked like before and after adding the `<a>`? There's a good chance that some additional CSS rule (not currently included in your question) is breaking things, but without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's really hard for us to determine the cause of this issue.

Comment: Two things: First, you said your image has a size attribute, but it doesn't. Second, why are you putting the image inside a `<header>` tag?

Comment: @Patrick Collins Please provide additional context. What are the styles on `ImageListItem`. What exactly is it? Any other styles that are relevant. Consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've added some context. I'm a little newer to frontend, is there a way to make react snippets?

Comment: You can add a link to a jsfiddle (free). It's a playground where you can write HTML/CSS/JS and you can also choose a framework like react or angular https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I think it's something to do with where the a tags are placed. Putting the a tags outside make it work

Answer (score 1):

The quick response is because yow styles said that them images inside yow header are going to have this styles

```
header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

The problem is in your html. Html has rules AND one of them rules is that block tags should not be in side of inline tags
`header` tag is a block tag `a` is inline

If you want to override that rule in your css you need to specify that `a` tags are block tags as well with

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the `a` tag instead of the `img`

```
header a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` is being set to 100% width of its parent, and 50% width of its parent. It's possible, that if you add the `a` tag, and the `a` element's width and height are not what you expect, that you'd see a change in behavior. But out of the box, without other styles applied, it shouldn't change anything.

For instance, this vanilla code, shows no difference in img sizing with or without the `a` element.

```css
header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header><img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt=""></header>

<a href="#">
  <header><img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt=""></header>
</a>
```

Comment: Exactly with or without <a> tag doesn't show any difference.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't able to see a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the problem you mentioned but I did not encounter any bug, please tell me more about your problem if my code does not solve your problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <style>
        a header img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <a href="#">
            <header>
                <img src="img1.jpg" alt="">
            </header>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say why your problem arises without knowing the styling of the other elements. So I am guessing that the display property is at fault here. The default display property of an `<a>` tag is `display:inline` while the header has the default display property of `display:block`. `display:inline` will not fill the parent horizontally but `display:block` does. I will show you in a code snippet example:

```css
.wrapper
{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:green;
}

.case1
{
  background:red;
}

.case2
{
  background:yellow;
}

.case3
{
  display:block;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="case1" >&lt;header&gt; display:block (default)</header>
  <a class="case2" >&lt;a&gt; display:inline (default)</a>
  <a class="case3" >&lt;a&gt; display:block</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see the parent of your image differs when you changed tags. The yellow area (case 2) is the same as you have now, in your case the `<header>` inside will be the same width as the `<a>` since it will not grow outside its parent. What you could try is to give your `<a>` tag the same display property as the header would have. Shown in case 3 with the orange background.

Comment: Nope, this didn't do anything. What other information would you need to see?

Comment: The width and height of the parent are important to reproduce your issue. If we had a code snippet we can use the Chrome debugger tools to look at what goes wrong. I don't know if you are familiar with chrome debugging tools but with this tool you can see the dimensions of each element. From that, you can see what goes wrong and live edit the CSS rules to fix it.

Comment: Or a screenshot of the differences between the two cases would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

## CSS property behaviour

You cannot change an element's height unless the parent's height is defined. Since you didn't share all the relevant code, I'm assuming you didn't set any rules for the `header`.

1. In this case, all you need to do is specify a `height` property on `header` and you're good to go.
2. If you already did, then you should share all the relevant code, because I wasn't able to reproduce your problem.

---

**Note:** *If you don't I'll have to flag this question for the lack of information, because it cannot be answered in it's current state!*

Answer (score 0):

Did this affect your css?
I'm also using ImageList for a project, when I put the anchor tags outside of ImageListItem the size of the images is stretched.
Here is the code, any suggestions on how to stop the images size/shape from being changed would be appreciated.

```
    {itemData.map(item =>(
          <a href={item.imghref}>
          <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
           <img src={`${item.img}?w=164&h=164&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2`} 
           alt='item.title' loading='lazy' />
          <ImageListItemBar
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={item.author}
            actionIcon={
              <IconButton
                sx={{ color: 'rgba(255, 255, 240, 0.54)' }}
                aria-label={`info about ${item.title}`}
              >
              </IconButton>
            }
          />
          </ImageListItem>
          </a>
        ))}
CSS:

    .imgs__list{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: 'hidden';
      padding:2rem 1rem ;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .imgs__list img{
      cursor: pointer;
      transition:0.2s;
    }
    
    .imgs__list img:hover{
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow:2.25px 4.25px 7.25px #121213;
      transform:scale(0.970);
    }
    
    .MuiImageListItemBar-root{
      transition: 0.2s;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .imgs__list :hover ~ .MuiImageListItemBar-root{
      transform:scale(0.970);
    }
```